# "Not Declared in scope" in Function in C++ using Code:Blocks on Linux

Tags: c++, function, addition

This is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "rlutil.h"
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


    int getNumber()
    {
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;
        cout << "Please Enter Your First Number." << endl;
        cin >> firstNumber;
        cout << "Please Enter Your Second Number." << endl;
        cin >> secondNumber;
        return 0;
    }

    int writeNumber()
    {
        getNumber();
        rlutil::setColor(3);
        cout << firstNumber + secondNumber << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

When I compile it to check for errors it gives me:

/home/bresser/Documents/LearnC++/main.cpp||In function ‘int writeNumber()’:|
/home/bresser/Documents/LearnC++/main.cpp|24|error: ‘firstNumber’ was not declared in this scope|
/home/bresser/Documents/LearnC++/main.cpp|24|error: ‘secondNumber’ was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I kind of understand what its saying just don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: The concept of scoped variables is fundamental to the language. Can you tell us what resource you are using to learn C++? If not, we can recommend [several good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fix is take

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
```

out of the getNumber function and give them global scope.  That is, put them just under the `using namespace std;` line in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring firstNumber and secondNumber inside getNumber(), writeNumber() is not able to reach them. You could do it like this (use [pass by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)) if you don't want to move the variables to global scope:

```
void getNumber(int &firstNumber, int &secondNumber)
{
    cout << "Please Enter Your First Number." << endl;
    cin >> firstNumber;
    cout << "Please Enter Your Second Number." << endl;
    cin >> secondNumber;
}

int writeNumber()
{
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    getNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    rlutil::setColor(3);
    cout << firstNumber + secondNumber << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the two variables (`firstNumber` and `secondNumber`) are out of scope - that is the second method can't 'see' them because they are declared in the first method.

Making these variables global will fix the problem - just move:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
```

to the top, above your definition of `getNumber()`.